# How to make boostrap sidebar default closed?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, jquery-ui, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make the sidebar to be collapsed as default when I load the page. Currently when I click on the collapse button which is on the sidebar, it collapses. How can I do that?

The html code

```
 <div class="wrapper">
   <nav id="sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar-header">
      <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info">
          <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>                  
      </button>
  </div>

        <ul class="list-unstyled components">
          <li class="nav-item active">
           ----------------
        </ul>

    </nav>    
      <div id="base" class="col pt-2" style="overflow: auto;">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The js function

```
$('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
    $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
  });

  $("#sidebar .nav-item").on("click", function () {
    $("#sidebar .nav-item").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
```

The css code:

```
    #sidebar {
        min-width: 80px;
        max-width: 80px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #sidebar.active {
        margin-left: 0 !important;
    }
    #sidebar .sidebar-header h3,
    #sidebar .CTAs {
        display: none;
    }
    #sidebar .sidebar-header strong {
        display: block;
    }
    #sidebar {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    #sidebarCollapse span {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please create the fiddle. The css code is missing.

Comment: I added that now

Comment: I'am not able to reproduce your issue. Please add the working fiddle, I mean reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

if you use Jquery, try this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggle");});
```

Or HTML option:

```
<div id="wrapper" class="toggled">
```

Please check the other questions here, before ask.